# How redis-py and Celery version select?

Tags: redis, celery

My Redis‘s version is 4.1.1,how I select redis-py and Celery version? I used celery 5.0.5 and redis-py 3.5.3 ，but it occured error

Comment: how do you choose the versions of Celery and redis-py?

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade to either latest 4.x or 5.x Celery.